# What is the general feeling for Hilbert's 10th problem for Q?

Tags: diophantine-equations, decidability

We know that Hilbert's 10th problem for $\mathbb{Z}$ is undecidable. I was wondering whether there is a strong opinion in the mathematical community on the decidability of Hilbert's 10th for $\mathbb{Q}$ and, if so, what are the motivations for such a strong opinion.

Comment: Have you read http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/h10_notices.pdf ? It implicitly gives several good arguments for both sides, without endorsing either.

Comment: It might be good to point out that the related question as to whether $\mathbb{Z}$ is existentially definable in $\mathbb{Q}$ is believed to have a negative answer; see corollary 23 here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.3424.pdf .